# How to convert Lightroom review data to jpeg

Tags: photos, adobe-lightroom

I lost orignal photo files because replace folder in OSX.

Can I convert lrdata to photo file? or export review file to photo file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lrData  file is simply a database of image previews/thumbnails.
You cannot use it to recreate lost photographs.

The best you could hope for would be to extract the thumbs as separate images, but they would have very little detail.

Comment: That what I want. Better than get not thing. T_T

Comment: Extract preview by adobe [https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/extract-previews-lightroom-4.html](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/extract-previews-lightroom-4.html)

Comment: The URL of the page is now https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/kb/extract-previews-for-lost-images-lightroom.html